# Posso usar uma variável para sobrescrever um método?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, método

Quando vou reescrever um método, em PHP, posso usar uma variável para receber o método?

Fiz o exemplo abaixo e funcionou normalmente, porém não sei se isso é correto ou se é a melhor forma de reescrever um método da classe-pai.

```
abstract class Animal{
  ...
  public function dadosAnimal(){
    $dados  = " Nome: ". $this->nome;
    $dados .= "Idade: ". $this->idade;

    return $dados;
  }

class Cachorro extends Animal(){
   ...
   public function dadosAnimal(){
     //Posso fazer ou vai contra algum principio ou patter ?
     $dados = parent:: dadosAnimal();
     $dados .= " Cor do pelo: ". $this->corPelo;

     return $dados;
}
```

O que eu quero é não ter que ficar repetindo o mesmo código da classe pai nas classes filhas e também ter o beneficio de alterar alguma coisa apenas na classe pai e a mudança se refletir para todos as classes filhas que usam o método do classe pai.

Evitar isso:

```
public function dadosAnimal(){
    parent::dadosAnimal();
    //Copiar o método inteiro da classe-pai
    $dados = "<br/> Nome: ". $this->nome;
    $dados .= "<br/> Idade: ". $this->idade;
    //reescrever, adicionando isso
    $dados .= "<br/> Cor do pêlo: ". $this->corPelo;

    return $dados;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta correto sim. Em vários casos queremos apenas adicionar um comportamento a um método herdado. Ou seja, queremos que, além do comportamento da classe pai, uma nova ação seja tomada. Nestes casos chamamos o método pai utilizando a referência `parent::`.

No seu caso, o comportamento do método pai é retornar uma descrição do `Animal`, e o comportamento que você deseja adicionar é o de retornar informações do pêlo, relacionadadas com a classe `Cachorro`, que extende a classe `Animal`.

Poderia haver problema no caso de você reescrever o comando `Animal::dadosAnimal()` na sua classe `Cachorro` do seguinte modo:

```
public function dadosAnimal(){
    $dados  = " Nome: ". $this->nome;
    $dados .= "Idade: ". $this->idade;
    $dados .= " Cor do pelo: ". $this->corPelo;
    return $dados;
}
```

Caso sua intenção fosse esconder completamente o comportamento do da classe `Animal` neste método, implementar deste modo seria um problema. Imagine o seguinte cenário: além da classe `Cachorro`, você possui `Gato`, `Passaro`, etc. Você escreve as classes, replicando o comportamento da classe `Animal` tal qual o exemplo acima.

Depois de um tempo você decide que não quer mais que o "nome" seja exibido no seu método `dadosAnimal()`. O que você faz? Percorre todas as classes removendo a parte do "nome". Não seria muito mais fácil se pudesse remover em apenas um lugar e todos os outros automagicamente tivessem seus nomes removidos?

Este é um exemplo de reuso de código, e é obtido da maneira como você escreveu, que é, portanto, a maneira indicada caso não se deseja esconder o comportamento de um método de uma classe precedente hierarquicamente.

Vale notar, que na linha `$dados = parent:: dadosAnimal();` você não está atribuindo um método à `$dados`, e sim atribuindo o resultado do método `parent::dadosAnimal()` há ela. Para atribuir um método, não se deve realizar a chamada, ocultando os parênteses `()`. Deste modo, estaria errado neste contexto.

Comment: o que quero ter como beneficio é exatamente isso, de poder alterar alguma coisa no método da classe pai e isso ser refletido para que está usando o método, sem q seja necessário alterar que está "herdando".

Comment: Neste caso, você esta fazendo do jeito correto. Desculpe se não ficou claro na resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Não há problema algum em fazer isto.

Mas sua pergunta não parece fazer muito sentido. Acho que você pensa que está fazendo algo que não está. Se eu entendi o que quis dizer.

> posso usar uma varável para sobrescrever um método?

Isto simplesmente não é possível. Tanto que você não fez isto.

Variáveis são usadas para dar nome a uma posição de memória que irá guardar dados. Ora, se um método retorna dados, uma variável dar nome a uma posição de memória onde estão esses dados é o normal. Não interprete o conceito de uma variável mais do que isto. Claro que existem alguns detalhes que não vem ao caso agora mas variável é só isto.

A grosso modo podemos dizer que uma variável guarda dados. Isto é um conceito errado mas não importa muito para quem está começando. No caso você apenas está guardando dados retornados pelo método, não está sobrescrevendo ele. Não está alterando nada definido na classe superior, não está complicando a orientação a objeto, enfim não está fazendo nada que seja anormal.

**EU** mudaria um pouco este código, eu odeio criação de variáveis quando os dados puros podem ser usados sem problemas (há quem pense diferente):

```
abstract class Animal {
  ...
  public function dadosAnimal() {
    return " Nome: " . $this->nome . "Idade: " . $this->idade;
  }

class Cachorro extends Animal() {
   ...
   public function dadosAnimal() {
     return parent::dadosAnimal() . " Cor do pelo: " . $this->corPelo;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Override.php).